# Problem when trying to run shell script : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to run the following command on bash:

```
./home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

which is giving me a

```
bash: ./home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm: No such file or directory
```

`rvm` is a bash file, and it does run ok when I attempt to run it from its own folder (`production_x86_64-linux`). It works also fine if I attempt to run it when opening the terminal in its parent folder, for instance, or even its parent-parent folder.

I've run it over with `dos2unix` just in case and I've also checked its executing permissions, which seem to be fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have two different paths so I am guessing a typo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can run a bash script by using the following command

```
bash <location of the script file>
```

in your case

```
bash /home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

it will work

what basically the . means is your current directory location.

if you are under your `<user>` folder then try doing this

```
./Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

it will work but first you should make the file executable using the following command

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I have an executable (.ish) file located deep in directory. So, I have set an alias in my bash. When I try to run it from other directory, it shows error. Let me show:
pro@prasanta-desktop:~$ studio
bash: ./home/pro/Downloads/Software/studio.ish: No such file or directory
in my bash, I have defined,
alias studio='./home/pro/Downloads/Software/studio.ish'
However, going in that directory and running ./studio.ish runs the program perfectly, what can be the issue then?

Answer (score 4):

While you are trying:

```
./home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

shell will always treat `.` in front of a path as current directory and hence the path will always be a relative path. So, shell is trying to find an executable file in the location:

```
$PWD/home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

which is wrong as you can see. You would run a executable script that is the current directory as `./script.sh`.

You can actually simply run the executable by using the absolute path (given the script is executable):

```
/home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

Or as `~` is expaneded by shell as `$HOME`:

```
~/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

Or even just the name of the script if the directory containing the script is in the `PATH` environment variable.

Now if your script is **Not executable**, you can run it too **without making it an executable** by telling the shell which program will handle the script i.e. giving the script as an argument to `bash` (shell):

```
bash /home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `./` to execute a file, it will look in the current folder (`.`) for a folder named `home` instead of starting from the root (`/`) directory.

Using the `bash` command explicitly like in bolzano's answer starts from the root directory instead of the one you're in.

To use the command without `bash` you could enter

```
/home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

or

```
Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/prototype_x86_64-linux/rvm
```

from your home directory assuming it is marked executable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers
What you tried was almost fine... But you forgot the extension `.sh`
- In your case
`./home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm.sh`
- or
`cd /home/abcdef/Desktop/jikesrvm/dist/production_x86_64-linux`
`./rvm.sh`